# How to handle Symfony form collection with 500+ items

Tags: php, forms, symfony, bulkinsert, bulk

I have form collection which need to handle more than 500 entity instances. After I increased timeout to 60s and increased max_input_vars form work but it is annoying how slow it is. Rendering form is slow but submitting that big form is pain in the ass.

I was considering creating plain HTML form but there is some other drawback suck as validation.
So, is there any proper way to handle that big set of data via symfony form ?

CONTROLLER:

```
public function ratesCardAction() {
    $bannerList = $this->data;

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AdvertiserRatesType($bannerList));
    if ('POST' == $this->getRequest()->getMethod()) {
        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
        $advertiserCampaign = $form->getData();
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($advertiserCampaign['campaignsAdZones'] as $campaignAdZone) {
               $em->persist($campaignAdZone);
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}



class AdvertiserRatesType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder ->add('campaignsAdZones', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => new AdvertiserRatePerCountryType(),
            'data'   => $this->rates,
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'options'  => array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'campaignAdZoneItem')
            )
        ))
        ;
    }

}
```

...

and embedded form looks like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('class', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeCmsBundle:PublisherTypes',
                'property' => 'class',
                'read_only' => true,
                'disabled' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeCmsBundle:Countries',
                'property' => 'name',
            )
        )
        ->add('text1')
        ->add('text2')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\CmsBundle\Entity\Rates'
    ));
}
```

Comment: In what specific place you have 500+ entities(500 countries, 500 types, or in collection 500 items)? How many calls to the database is going on?

Comment: I have 500 items inside collection. So, my POST request data has 500 instances of Acme\CmsBundle\Entity\Rates object: array(0=>Acme\CmsBundle\Entity\Rates, 1=>Acme\CmsBundle\Entity\Rates, .... 500=>Acme\CmsBundle\Entity\Rates)

Comment: You should try to split the form into small pieces with something like a pagination.

Comment: I would but this solution isn't acceptable by client :) I went with building plain HTML form and skip symfony form for now. Yeah, i know i will have a little bit more job to handle validation and all other things sf form do it automatically. Rendering as well as submiting action are 5X faster....

Comment: Have you tried using profiler to identify the cause? Have you looked to Doctrine produced sql statements? It's really not worth giving up the Symfony Form / Doctrine because of this. One cause that comes to mind is that your code attempts to update each record regardless if it was modified by user or not. Also, if possible, use hydration to arrays instead of objects, fetch only required columns instead of all.

Comment: Hi @TadasSasnauskas, I have a similar problem. Could you please give me more details on how to fetch only required columns instead of all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed using whole entities to collection with over 500 items is an overkill ;)

First: use pure arrays instead of entities, set `'data_class' => null` in `setDefaultOptions` method

Second: You do not want to create over 500 new items on one page form, do You? ;) If it is really needed for some reason and it has to be done like that... well currently `$advertiserCampaign = $form->getData();` in Your code will return over 500 objects - HEAVY. Instead of that, `$advertiserCampaign = $form->getData();` should return 500 arrays of data and THEN inside foreach You should create new object and bind data to it (e.g. using datatransfomer).
Validation still may be handled with no problem - just set validators for each field inside form class.

Third: I hope that `$this->rates` is not another collection of objects - right? In case it is - use primitive array instead of heavy objects.

Fourth: 500 objects/forms on one page? REALLY? Might it be refactored somehow? Maybe pagination and e.g. 20 forms per page?
If You really, really need to save 500 objects from one form in one request, then I suggest, to use some Queue handler like RabbitMQ or Gearman  to save all 500 objects in database.

I hope that helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the Doctrine query cache ? You're typically in a case where caches are a common solution.

- https://coderwall.com/p/ry1y0a
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html

See about other Symfony caches as well, and don't hesitate to test as many PHP cache solutions as you find (see last link).

Comment: I Symfony's Form Componetn is the bottle neck here. 500+ records is no problem for Doctrine.