# Pagination of a Symfony form collection with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: forms, symfony, formcollection, knppaginator

like in [How to handle Symfony form collection with 500+ items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718952/how-to-handle-symfony-form-collection-with-500-items) i have got a big  symfony form collection. In the mentioned thread someone suggests to use pagination for the collection.

How can i paginate such a form collection with the knpPaginatorBundle?

The form type is like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('myType', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new MyType(),
        ))
    ;
}
```

My controller generates a form with the collection

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormCollectionType());
```

and then i'm trying to use the paginator

```
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $form['myType'],
    $request->get('page', 1),
    10
);
```

I think i'm using the wrong target for paginate($target), whats the correct target in a symfony form collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example on Symfony3 :

**Catalog Controller**

```
// I want to paginate products (my collection)
$products = $catalog->getProducts();   // ArrayCollection

// Pagination
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($products, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 10);

// build the form with catalog data
$form = $this->createForm(CatalogProductType::class, $catalog, array("pagination" => $pagination));

// [...]

// show page
return $this->render('catalogs/products.html.twig', array(
    'catalog'    => $catalog,
    'form'       => $form->createView(),
    'pagination' => $pagination
));
```

**Catalog Form (CatalogProductType)**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('products',   CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'    => ProductType::class,
            'data'          => $options['pagination'],
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'prototype'     => true,
            'label'         => false,
            'by_reference'  => false
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'attr'    => array('class' => 'button-link save'),
            'label'   => 'Validate'
        ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'    => 'AppBundle\Entity\Catalog',
        'pagination'    => null    // Don't forget this !
    ));
}
```

**My view (products.html.twig)**

```
<div class="navigation">{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}</div>

{% if pagination.getTotalItemCount > 0 %}
    {% for widget in form.products.children %}
        {# Refers to a Twig macro #}
        {{ _self.prototype_product(widget) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="error">The is no product in this catalog</div>
{% endif %}
```

> > My products collection is now paginated.

Comment: When submitting a collection of has 1000's of objects, and a page size of 10, it seems to remove everything except what's on the current page.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have an entity with a collection of 2000 items and it works. The entity form that contains the paginated collection does'nt remove a part of my collection when I submit it.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:
Query all entities of the collection, paginate these and set the data attribute of the collection to the paginated value.

Controller:

```
$allEntities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->findAll();
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $allEntities,
    $request->get('page', 1),
    10
);

$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormCollectionType($pagination));
```

Form type:

```
private $data;

public function __construct($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('myType', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new MyType(),
            'data' => $this->data,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this, approach, but this seems to be able to loose some data when updating a colleciton. Given you have two users editing the same collection page. One user remove first item from collection, and then second user updated first item on collection. As soon as pagination was performed - second item will be overwritten with updated data of first item.

Comment: Yeah, recover all entries from the DataBase then, and only then, do the pagination. wonder if this works in a 1 000 000 entry table.....

Comment: This seems to only keep the current page of items in the collection.